# AIX UNIX 64 bit connecting to Microsoft SQL server 2008R2 Server

Tags: windows, aix

I am having AIX 64 bit Unix machine and I need to connect to Microsoft SQL SERVER 2008 R2 database.
I dont have any Drivers and TDS installed in my machine.
What all tools I need to install including any dependencies?

Comment: Your question is realy incomplete - Please expand it to say what you want to achieve?  Do you want to do development?  Do you have a COTS application?  Having said that, this information will be included in your application documentation, particularly if it is an enterprise off-the-shelf application.  Typically if the application does not have built-in support for connecting to a remote database, there will be a list of pre-requisites with minimum version numbers.

Comment: @Johan : You are correct, The application needs to insert the lines of a file using shell script to sql server database.It does not have built in support for connecting to a remote database.I need the list of prerequisites.Thanks..

Comment: @Johan :I an running Unix AIX 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Contact the application vendor or developer for a list of pre-requisites.  Some applications have built-in capabilities of connecting to databases, others require plug-ins or depend on ODBC drivers.